# Структура C#

Tags: c#, классы, структуры

Доброго вечера! Сделал массив структуры в отдельном классе, но, к сожалению, цикл заполняет массив только в первой итерации насколько мне удалось выяснить, как это решить ума ни прилажу. Проверял это выводом MessageBox(Convert.ToString(i));, но выводилось только 1 раз и все. Были идеи, что в отличии от Delphi в C# запрещено слишком часто выводить всплывающие окна, но попробовав вывести MessageBox(Convert.ToString(B[80].X)) при массиве в кол-ве 100 элементов он мне выводил 0, как будто до него не дошло.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Sorting
{
    class MainArray
    {
        protected struct StructArray 
        {
           internal short X,Value;
           internal byte R, G, B;
        }

    protected Random Random;

    protected StructArray[] B;

    //Конструктор класса
    public MainArray(ushort Count)
    {
        B = new StructArray[Count];
        StructArray myElem = new StructArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {                
            myElem.X = Convert.ToInt16(i*10);
            myElem.Value = Convert.ToInt16(Random.Next(1025));
            myElem.R = Convert.ToByte(Random.Next(256));
            myElem.G = Convert.ToByte(Random.Next(256));
            myElem.B = Convert.ToByte(Random.Next(256));

            B[i] = myElem;                
        }
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(B[80].X));
    }

    //Конструктор для потомков
    public MainArray()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Random** надо во что-нибудь переименовать (например **Rnd**)

В конструкторе вы забыли:

```
Rnd = new Random();
```

Вроде работает всё.

Comment: Господи такая простая ошибка... Огроменное вам спасибо! Я уже третий час ломаю голову!